# Count down clock - getting the difference between two times

Tags: vb.net

stuck on a simple one.
I have an project that will count down to a start time, the start time is generated from a datetime picker,("HH:mm"), when a button is clicked the time .now is subtracted and the timespan is passed to a timer for the countdown.
a rough outline of the code is

Aa4 is the output from the DateTime picker

```
Dim Span3
Dim TimetoStart as date 
TimetoStart = TimeOfDay.Date 'get current time
Span3=StartTime.Subtract(Aa4) 'Subtract current time from output from datetime picker
LaBel4.text=span3 'Output to label (will be timer later for count down)
```

Error generated is system.invalidcastexception 'conversion from type timespan to type string is not valid.

As I said at the start it will be easy, I am not seeing it and its doing my head in, cheers all Daz

Comment: Label4.text=span3.ToString().

Comment: If you declared the data type for `Span3` (`Dim Span3 as TimeSpan`), I think that you would have discovered the answer which @Hursey mentioned.

Comment: Brilliant stuff thanks everyone, knew it was simple. Again thanks

Comment: You should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties immediately and fix all the errors that are flagged. You should also turn it `On` in the VS options, so it will be `On` by default for all future projects. ALWAYS have `Option Strict On` at the project level. In a project that specifically requires late binding, which you may never actually have, you can turn it `Off` at the file level in only those files that specifically need it, using partial classes to keep the code in those files to an absolute minimum.